# Ajax function call: parameter passing to controller function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, codeigniter-3

I am working on codeigniter. I am calling ajax function in a view page. Ajax 
    function is calling controller method. Ajax function is containing 3 
    parameters which i want to pass to controller method but due to some reason i 
        am not able to access parameter which is coming from ajax function.

Below is the my view code :

```
<script>  
$('#drp').change(function(e){  
      var costcenter = $('#costcenter_id :selected').val(); 
      var location1 = $('#location_id :selected').val(); 
      var department = $('#department_id :selected').val(); 
      $.ajax({
         cashe: false,
         type: 'POST',
         data:  {'costcenterid':costcenter,'locationid':location1,
                 'departmentid':department},
         url: 'http://local.desk.in/mycontroller/contollerfunction',
success: function(data)
            {
               alert("success");
            }
      });
    });
 </script>
// controller method
public function controllerfunction($costcenterid,$locationid,$departmentid)
    {
    echo "costcenter= ". $costcenterid; 
    echo "location= ". $locationid; 
    echo "department= ". $departmentid;
    }
```

> Getting error message :
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction(), 
>      Message: Missing argument 2 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction(), 
>      Message: Missing argument 3 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction()

Why not able to send ajax parameter values to controller method?? Thanks in 
    advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You are passing data as post in ajax so you have to access your data by using `$_POST` or using CI input class like `$this->input->post()`* and for url path use `site_url()`

Your `ajax` code should be like this :

```
$('#drp').change(function(e){  
    var costcenter = $('#costcenter_id :selected').val(); 
    var location1 = $('#location_id :selected').val(); 
    var department = $('#department_id :selected').val(); 
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  {'costcenterid':costcenter,'locationid':location1,
         'departmentid':department},
        url: "<?=site_url('mycontroller/contollerfunction');?>",
        success: function(data)
        {
           alert("success");
        }
    });
});
```

*And your controller `controllerfunction` method should be like this :*

```
public function controllerfunction()
{
    $costcenterid = $this->input->post('costcenterid');
    $locationid = $this->input->post('locationid');
    $departmentid = $this->input->post('departmentid');
    $posts = array('costcenterid' => $costcenterid,
                   'locationid' => $locationid,
                   'departmentid' => $departmentid);
    print_r($posts);die;
}
```

**Note : see your browser's network tab to see the output :**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried as you suggested now i can access all parameter's values in controller method. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Can you please suggest what is the best way to debug a PHP program? Is there any editor available to write and debug PHP program? Thanks in advance.